# Is it impossible to pack too much information in the space of sufficiently smooth functions?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

*The basic version of my question is:* am I right that there doesn't exist an infinite sequence of mutually orthogonal functions $f_i\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ which are sufficiently smooth, e.g. Lipschitz-continuous with the same constant? My loose intuition is that the existence of such an infinite sequence would require packing too much information in the space of those functions which should not be possible.

*The full version is:* for a uniform random variable $x\sim U[0,1]$ and a sequence of sufficiently smooth functions $f_i(x)$ for $i=1,\dots$, under what conditions does it follow that whenever $Var(f_i(x))\ge a>0$, $\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i,j=1}^n\left|Cov(f_i(x),f_j(x))\right|$ cannot converge to zero as $n\to\infty$. The intuition again is that one can't have covariances too close to zero for all but a small fraction of the pairs of these smooth functions. (Showing this for a general multivariate $x$ would be even better. Or limiting to monotone functions, such that all covariances are non-negative, could be good enough, too.)

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: Well, you could take the $f_i$ to be the Legendre polynomials. I don't know what their Lipschitz constants are.

Comment: You probably want lower bound on $L_2$ norm in basic version of question too, otherwise take any sequence of mutually orthogonal smooth functions and divide each by its Lipschitz constant.

Comment: Yes, agreed, same lower bound on $L_2$ norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(everywhere below $\|\cdot\|$ denotes $L_2$ norm)

If you, similar to full version, require that $\|f_i\| \geq a > 0$, then it's not possible.

For simplicity, assume that Lipschitz constant of every function is at most $1$ and $a < 1$. Then if function changes sign, it's absolute value is at most $1$ in every point. And all but at most two functions have to change sign (because two everywhere positive or two everywhere negative functions are not orthogonal). Discarding them, we now have infinite sequence of functions each taking absolute values of at most $1$.

Let $h(x) = \lceil x / \varepsilon\rceil \cdot \varepsilon$ - rounding with precision of $\varepsilon$. Let $g_i(x) = h(f_i(h(x)))$ - simple function that takes values $n\varepsilon$ that represents "rounding" of $f$ both for argument and value.

Note that $\|g_i - f_i\| < 3\varepsilon$ (because of Lipschitz restriction) and $|g_i(x)| < 1 + 2 \varepsilon$.

Take $\varepsilon = a / 8$. There are finitely many possible $g_i$, so we have $g_i = g_j$ for some $i, j$.

Now, we have
$$2 (f_i, f_j) = \|f_i\|^2 + \|f_j\|^2 - \|f_i - f_j\|^2\geq\\
2a^2 - \|f_i - g_i + g_i - g_j + g_j - f_j\|^2 \geq \\
2a^2 - (\|f_i - g_i\| + \|g_i - g_j\| + \|g_j - f_j\|)^2 \geq \\
2a^2 - (3a / 8 + 0 + 3a / 8)^2 > 22/16 a^2 > 0$$

Comment: Thanks so much! Is sounds like our construction should solve the full question too: there should be at least one of these rounded functions such that the share of i corresponding to it is bounded from below by some s>0 for large enough n. Thus, at least s^2 pairs (i,j) have a covariance of at least 22/16a^2, and thus the average absolute covariance is $\ge s^2\cdot 22/16a^2$. Does that sound right?

Comment: And it should generalize to $x\sim U[0,1]^k$ for any finite $k$ just as well, by rounding each coordinate.

Comment: I think we need to switch quantifiers: there is some $s$ s.t. for every $n$, there is a rounded function with share greater than $s$ (it can be different rounded function for different $n$). And that indeed should work for multidimensional case.

Comment: Hi @mihaild, quick question: why do you bound $\|g_i-f_i\|$ by $3\varepsilon$ rather than $2\varepsilon$. One epsilon is from rounding the argument, the other from rounding the value - what am I missing?
And also, we'd like to thank you in the paper - what name should we use?

Comment: @KirillBorusyak because I wanted strict inequality (but we don't actually need it). We indeed have $|h(x) - x| \leq \epsilon$ and so $|h(f_i(h(x))) - f_i(x)| \leq |h(f_i(h(x))) - f_i(h(x))| + |f_i(h(x)) - f_i(x)| \leq 2\varepsilon$. My name is Mikhail Dektiarev, if you think such "big" contribution worth mentioning:)